# How to write partitioned parquet files to blob storage

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-data-factory

I want to load data from On Premise SQL SERVER to blob storage with copy activity in ADF, the target file is parquet, the size of this one is 5 Gb.

The pipeline work well and he wrote one parquet file, now i need to split this file in multiple parquet file to optimise loading data with Poly base and for another uses.

With Spark we can partition file in multiple file by this syntaxe :

df.repartition(5).write.parquet("path")

Answer (score 1):

Short question, short answer.

Partitioned data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-read-write-partitioned-data

Parquet format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet

Blob storage connector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thx for response, but i note that i don't talk about partionning path, i'm looking for partioning file.

Comment: Data factory doesn't manipulate data on its own, you can do this with data flows now, running on the back of a databricks cluster: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-optimize-tab